# Не могу запустить SpringMVC проект

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

После запуска проекта на jetty/tomcat выкидывает такой exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityContext': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.dronesfree.configuration.SecurityContext.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Самое забавное, что проект вчера запускался. После того как я переустановил себе ОС с win7 на ubuntu 14.04 проект перестал запускаться. БД установлена, подключение создано, все для разработки есть. Вот мой бин, который не может быть создан

SecurityContext:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.social.security.SocialUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.social.security.SpringSocialConfigurer;

import com.dronesfree.security.service.RepositoryUserDetailsService;
import com.dronesfree.security.service.SimpleSocialUserDetailsService;
import com.dronesfree.user.service.UserService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityContext extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(
                passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
        // Configures form login
        .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login/authenticate")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=bad_credentials")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                // Configures the logout function
                .and()
                .logout()
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                // Configures url based authorization
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                // Anyone can access the urls
                .antMatchers("/", "/auth/**", "/login", "/signup/**",
                        "/user/register/**")
                .permitAll()
                // The rest of the our application is protected.
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                // Adds the SocialAuthenticationFilter to Spring Security's
                // filter chain.
                .and().csrf().and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/403").and()
                .apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
        // Spring Security ignores request to static resources such as CSS or JS
        // files.
        .ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**");
    }

    @Bean(name = "passwordEncoder")
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SocialUserDetailsService socialUserDetailsService() {
        return new SimpleSocialUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new RepositoryUserDetailsService(userService);
    }
}’
```

RepositoryUserDetailsService:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.dronesfree.security.dto.ExampleUserDetails;
import com.dronesfree.user.model.User;
import com.dronesfree.user.service.UserService;

@Service("userDetailsService")
public class RepositoryUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger
            .getLogger(RepositoryUserDetailsService.class);

    public RepositoryUserDetailsService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        LOGGER.debug("Loading user by username: {" + username + "}");

        User user = userService.getUserByUsername(username);
        LOGGER.debug("Found user: {" + user + "}");

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with username: "
                    + username);
        }

        ExampleUserDetails principal = ExampleUserDetails.getBuilder()
                .firstName(user.getFirstName()).id(user.getId())
                .lastName(user.getLastName()).password(user.getPassword())
                .role(user.getRole())
                .socialSignInProvider(user.getSignInProvider())
                .username(user.getUsername()).build();

        LOGGER.debug("Returning user details: {" + principal + "}");

        return principal;

    }

}
```

Comment: А зачем вам конструктор с параметром в бине? По идеи бины должны быть с дефолтным конструктором.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Spring (насколько понял, доки подробно не читал) есть следующий workflow:

- Spring находит необходимые пакеты, указанные в `@ComponentScan`, сканирует их на предмет классов, отмеченных `@Configuration`, `@Service`, `@Component`, `@Repository` и аналогичными аннотациями и загружает в контейнер
- Контейнер строит граф зависимостей всего это добра
- Spring запрашивает у контейнера все объявленные бины
- Контейнер разрешает дерево зависимостей для выбранного бина, используя `@Autowired` для определения этих зависимостей
- В случае наличия `@Autowired`-полей класс сначала создается, а затем они проставляются через рефлексию

Очевидно, на последнем этапе с данным классом у Spring возникнет проблема: он не может создать этот класс из-за отсутствия публичного конструктора. Однако `@Autowired` применим не только к полям, но и к конструкторам, поэтому стоит просто переместить аннотацию на конструктор (и даже более того - если достать из контейнера `AutowireCapableBeanFactory`, то можно вручную создавать любые классы, у которых в конструкторе указаны присутствующие в контейнере зависимости).

Comment: Не могу понять, почему проект запускался, а после переустановки ОС нет.

Comment: @АндрійДзигар я не знаю, но не понимаю, почему он до этого запускался. Вы точно не меняли версии зависимостей в промежутке между запусками?

Comment: Ничего не менял. Залил проект на GitHub, поменял ОС с Вин7 на Ubuntu. Встановил все необходимое и скопировал проект с GitHub. Проект запустился. Но поставил корявий Ubuntu и пришлось переустановлять. После этого сделал все тоже самое. Проек не запустился.